# .ReadWriteUserDetails does not define a no-argument constructor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im getting this error on my app after on line 109 adding a update profile class.

this is my UserProfileActivity.java

```
private void showUserProfile(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
    String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
    //Extract Data from databaseRegistered users
    DatabaseReference referenceProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Registered Users");
    referenceProfile.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ReadWriteUserDetails readUserDetails = snapshot.getValue(ReadWriteUserDetails.class);
            if (readUserDetails != null) {
                fullName = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
                email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
                dob = readUserDetails.dob;
                gender = readUserDetails.gender;
                mobile = readUserDetails.mobile;
                textViewShowWelcome.setText("Welcome, " + fullName + "!");
                textViewShowFullName.setText(fullName);
                textViewShowEmail.setText(email);
                textViewShowDob.setText(dob);
                textViewShowGender.setText(gender);
                textViewShowMobile.setText(mobile);
```

// this is my Read write

```
public class ReadWriteUserDetails {
    public String dob, gender, mobile, fullname;

    //Constructor
       public ReadWriteUserDetails(String textFullName, String textDob, String textGender, String textMobile) {

        this.dob = textDob;
        this.gender = textGender;
        this.mobile = textMobile;
        this.fullname = textFullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `snapshot.getValue` seemingly tries to utilize a paramerterless constructor to create a new instance of your class. But the only constructor you define has 4 parameters. So create an additional constructor without parameters